# Add "Percent Complete" chart based on two feature classes to Operations Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I am trying to create an Operations Dashboard in ArcGIS Online and want to track progress towards a goal.  The goal is a sum of features (count of potential_customers, subtyped as residential).  Progress is a sum of counts from a separate feature class of building_type where subtypes "single family" count once, but "duplex" count twice.

I would like to display a number representing percent complete, or maybe a graph depicting progress next to goal. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You talk about both ArcGIS Online and creating a dashboard and finding a tool. Can you confirm that your goal is to create an `Operations Dashboard`, a component of ArcGIS Online? Or do you want to create a map, other?

Comment: I'm editing a `Dashboard` in ArcGIS Online.  I'm not sure if it's the same thing as an `Operations Dashboard`, but I think those are synonymous, and I think that is what I am looking for.  I want to move around on the map, see my features, and off in a corner of the dashboard, I would like to display some measure of progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select a singular layer within your web map to use in a widget within operations dashboard, currently unable to link 2 or more layers into a widget

Comment: Then I could run some geoprocessing task that tabulates the results I need and then crams them into a table with two columns; one row: GOAL = 2000, PROGRESS = 1275.  I could turn that into a percent, right?  How can I get the geoprocessing task to run as part of this operations dashboard?

Comment: The dashboard utilizes layers in your table of contents in a webmap. You can run your task to update whenever you want, when the data is updated, the dashboard updates. You can add this table to your map, then use the table in your graphs/charts

Answer (score 0):

You could use a gauge widget to display overall progress.  You have to set the end value that your feature class is approaching.  You can set it to show as a fraction or as a percentage.  If your maximum vakue is changing though this will not work, it will only work with a constant maximum value.